# NullPointerException in main thread

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I would like to know, what is main by **NullPointerException**.

My understanding of this error code is that there is a variable with null value being used. But what does it really mean. Kindly seek your enlightenment.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)

at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)

at TicTacToe.<init>(TicTacToe.java:29)

at TicTacToe.main(TicTacToe.java:49)

public class TicTacToe {

JPanel t3pan;
JButton button1;
JButton button2;
JButton button3;
JButton button4;
JButton button5;
JButton button6;
JButton button7;
JButton button8;
JButton button9;

TicTacToe()
{
    t3pan = new JPanel();

    GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(3,3);
    t3pan.setLayout(gl);

      t3pan.add(button1);
      t3pan.add(button2);
      t3pan.add(button3);
      t3pan.add(button4);
      t3pan.add(button5);
      t3pan.add(button6);
      t3pan.add(button7);
      t3pan.add(button8);
      t3pan.add(button9);


    JFrame t3frame = new JFrame();

    t3frame.setContentPane(t3pan);
    t3frame.pack();
    t3frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new TicTacToe();
}

}
```

Comment: dont see any of those buttons initialized anywhere

Comment: The method *add throws NullPointerException* if *param* is *null*. [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29)

Comment: Negative vote for not looking at the API docs before posting question.

Comment: Thank you! Was careless on my part for not initialising.

But finally learn and understand one of the cause of nullpointerexception.

And thanks for the API, but if there is no one to enlighten, will still not understand just by looking at it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`button1` through `button9` are `null` (they have no value). You declared them, but you never instantiated them. You need something like,

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1"); //<-- for all 9.
```

The default value for a class field

```
JButton button1;
```

is `null`, so that is equivalent to

```
JButton button1 = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `button` variables are null because of which the lines `t3pan.add(button1)` and so on are failing with `NullPointerException`s.

You need to initialize the button variables before adding them to `t3pan`.

Comment: Thank you! Finally realised that what it really mean!